# Convert each element in tensor variable greater than 5 into 10

Tags: python, variables, tensor

For example, tensor variable `a` is:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to convert each element in tensor variable greater than 5 into 10.

that is, convert from `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 10]`.

Should I use `for` and `if` statements?

or is there a simpler coding?

thank you very much!

Comment: That `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],` defines `a` as a tuple of one element, which is a list of 6 elements. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please include what you have tried already, and a sample of your Python code in your question. Have you tried both methods? What difficulties are you having? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I think you mean *"greater or equal"* instead of *"greater"*.

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a10 = [elt if elt < 5 else 10 for elt in a]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However error message says "TypeError: 'Variable' object is not iterable."

Comment: remove the comma after `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],` in your code (not in my answer), or directly use the entire code provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example suggests that you want replace the numbers *greater or equal* to 5 to 10. A simple approach is to just update the list in place with a simple `for` loop:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i, number in enumerate(a):
    if number >= 5:
        a[i] = 10

print(a)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 10]
```